# onTouchListener in Android will detect touch on all parent view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have

```
 RelativeLayout

       A---BIG IMAGE
       B---MEDIUM IMAGE
       C---SMALL IMAGE
```

The picture is looking like this

[image]

I have used below java code

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                // LEFT
                case R.id.tblLOne:
                    System.out.println("IMG_L_A");
                    playBeep(TABLA_L_BIG);
                    changeLeftDrum();
                    break;
                case R.id.tblLTwo:
                    System.out.println("IMG_L_B");
                    playBeep(TABLA_L_MID);
                    changeLeftDrum();
                    break;
                case R.id.tblLThree:
                    System.out.println("IMG_L_C");
                    playBeep(TABLA_L_SMALL);
                    changeLeftDrum();
                    break;
                return false;
                }
                return true;

    }
```

Problem is that whenever I click on **small (BLACK) Image**

I got following output

```
IMG_L_A
IMG_L_B
IMG_L_C
```

Whenever I click on **Middle Image** I got

```
IMG_L_A
IMG_L_B
```

On **OuterImage big image**

```
IMG_L_A
```

**Why I am getting it's all behind ImageView's OnTouch Method**

It is working perfect with **onClick** but not with **OnTouch**

Answer (score 5):

It's because the views are stacked on top of each other.

The important point here is to know the importance of the Boolean flag that you return from your `onTouchListener`. The boolean flag tells android if the event was consumed or not.

Suppose, you touch `tblRthree`, the `case R.id.tblLThree` executes, but then since you return false, it appears to android that the event was not consumed and this event bubbles up to the `tblRTwo` view which is just behind `tblRthree` view, which executes the same listener for the `case R.id.tblLTwo` but then again you return false so, it bubbles up to view `tblROne` and all three cases execute.

You should return true whenever you consume the event, and false when you don't.

Comment: Thank you so much @Shivam +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

`onTouch` method will be called in multiple events, all you need is to check whether it is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` or not.

So, it will look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
             return false;//we are not going to handle it
            }  

            switch (v.getId()) {
            // LEFT
            case R.id.tblLOne:
                System.out.println("IMG_L_A");
                playBeep(TABLA_L_BIG);
                changeLeftDrum();
                break;
            case R.id.tblLTwo:
                System.out.println("IMG_L_B");
                playBeep(TABLA_L_MID);
                changeLeftDrum();
                break;
            case R.id.tblLThree:
                System.out.println("IMG_L_C");
                playBeep(TABLA_L_SMALL);
                changeLeftDrum();
                break;
            }
            return true;//we have handled it
}
```

Comment: this is a bad way. non-elegant reply.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov: what is bad about it? I have already specified reason and given the code with comments as well. anyways, you are free to edit if you feel so.

Comment: I don't say about your answer in stylistic context. I say about your answer as the elegant architectural  way to solve problem. But it solve.

Comment: Thank you so much @MehulJoisar +1 for that :)

Comment: It's not because of multiple events that the code doesn't work. It's because the code returns false even when the event is consumed that the code posted by OP doesn't work.